# Django Migrations does not apply changes in models

Tags: django, django-models

Whenever I add/remove/modify anything in models.py and the following commands the project does not make those changes to the database models.

python manage.py makemigrations

OR

python manage.py makemigrations

OR

Python manage.py migrate

All the above command throws the same error as below:
"
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column
"

Tried deleting the migrate folder (without deleting , running fake migrations , running zero migrations but nothing helped.

Please advise.

Models.py file is saved and includes:

class studentmaster(models.Model):

```
studentid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
studentname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
isstaff= models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

when running migrations, the complete trace is provided below:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column loginapp_studentmaster.isstaff does not exist
LINE 1: ...udentid", "loginapp_studentmaster"."studentname", "loginapp_...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 58, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 397, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ankit/smartswypetest/smartswypetest/UserLogin/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from loginapp import views
  File "/home/ankit/smartswypetest/smartswypetest/loginapp/views.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .forms import *
  File "/home/ankit/smartswypetest/smartswypetest/loginapp/forms.py", line 32, in <module>
    class AnnForm(forms.Form):
  File "/home/ankit/smartswypetest/smartswypetest/loginapp/forms.py", line 42, in AnnForm
    choices=[(str(s.studentid), s.studentname)for s in studentmaster.objects.all()],
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 272, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1066, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda3/envs/sswypeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column loginapp_studentmaster.isstaff does not exist
LINE 1: ...udentid", "loginapp_studentmaster"."studentname", "loginapp_...
```

Comment: The order in which you run those commands is important,you cannot just run these and hope for the best. Try running `migrate --fake`, `makemigrations` and then `migrate`.

Comment: Show the *full* error, properly formatted.

Comment: Thanks  scharette for the advice and the order.. But the migrations are still stuck there. @DanielRoseman  - I have edited the question with complete trace

Answer (score 0):

Your AnnForm is making a query in the class definition, which is executed at import time before the migrations can run.

You shouldn't write forms like this anyway. Use a ModelChoiceField with a queryset.